# In Chrome developer tools, under react tab it shows "looking for react" and freezes there

Tags: reactjs

I tried to debug the react application, after running the application and moving to the React tab on Chrome Developer tools, It shows

`"Looking for React"`

and freezes there, nothing shows up. 
But the application executes successfully and I am able to work on it, What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, only the React tab in the dev tools did work. My solution was to:

- Open the Chrome [extensions tab](http://chrome://extensions/), `chrome://extensions/`
- Disable the React dev tool
- Go to page where the React is not working
- Close devtools
- Reload web page and the chrome extension page (I think this checks for updates, not sure)
- Turn on React Developer Tools
- Re-open the React tool on the web page and it should be working again.

Answer (score 1):

This Happens when you do a server side rendering, So the React code is not available to the browser, try to render it on the client side. 
Ex:
  in Webpack, If you are running your application in the dev server mode like

```
webpack-dev-server
```

you will see "Looking for React" on the React tab of the Chrome Developer tools
change your url from

```
localhost://8080/webpack-dev-server/
```

to

```
localhost://8080/
```

your React tab loads, I have shown it for webpack, This is common for all run it on the client side.